# System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException for Send grid send email

Tags: c#, sockets, httprequest, sendgrid-api-v3

We are facing following exception in calling Sendgrid Send Email function in some case.
We get this exception for 20-30 emails out of 50,000 in a day.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Unknown error (0xffffffff)     
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UnsafeBeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)     
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
at SendGrid.Helpers.Reliability.RetryDelegatingHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
at SendGrid.BaseClient.<MakeRequest>d__20.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
at SendGrid.BaseClient.<RequestAsync>d__21.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
at SendGrid.BaseClient.<SendEmailAsync>d__22.MoveNext()  --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)     
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

My code to send email is

```
var client = new SendGridClient("API Key");
var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(message);
```

Can anyone please help me how can I add more verification to avoid such situation.

Comment: Have you considered to use retry logic in case of transient failure?

Comment: Not yet used. Shall I consider the retry logic?

Comment: It depends if SendGrid can handle retried requests in an idempotent way (so it will not send out a new email if it receives the same request) then yes. I also recommend to read [this](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#ret) to have better understanding how retry might have affect your current workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Retry logic did work for me so far.

```cs
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (--retryMax == 0)
    {
        throw;
    }
    else
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to fine tune your retry logic. In case of Polly for instance the `HandleTransientHttpError` method performs retries in case of `HttpRequestException` or in the HttpStatusCode is either `408` or greater than `500`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly)